# How to delete certain words from string without spaces?

Tags: python, string

Is there I way to delete words from a string in Python if it doesn't have spaces. For example, if you have the string `"WUBHELLOWUB"` I want to remove `"WUB"`. I tried

```
s = 'WUBHELLOWUB'
while 'WUB' in s:
    ind = s.find('WUB')
    s = s[:ind] + s[ind+1:]
    print(s)
```

but it did not work.

Comment: `s.replace('WUB', '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex

```
 import re
 data=r"\S*WUB\S*"
 re.sub(data, '','WUBWUBHELLO')
```